# utf characters when using user32.dll FindWindow in c# application

Tags: c#, utf-8, window, find, pinvoke

LS,
I am using FindWindow method in c# application to get window handle from web browser

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName );
```

it works well when the window title does not contain utf chars like here:

```
string caption1 = "pinvoke.net: findwindow (user32) - Google Chrome";
int hwnd = FindWindow(null, caption1);
```

but it fails when utf chars are present in window title:

```
string caption2 = "Słownik języka polskiego - Google Chrome";
int hwnd2 = FindWindow(null, caption2);
```

e.g. hwnd == 0

Would You please provide me with any suggestion how to get handle of browser window containing utf-8 chars in c# application.
Thanks in advance.

ps 
I have already seen the comment about using FindWindow with utf in c++, saying:
"You can explicitly use the Unicode version of the API
HWND windowHnd = FindWindowW(NULL, L"Minesweeper");"
but I still don't know how to do it properly in c#

Comment: There's no UTF-8 anywhere here. What you do have is UTF-16.

Comment: See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but you should be able to do this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName );
```

According to MSDN's article on the [DllImportAttribute.CharSet Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset.aspx), the default assumption will be `CharSet.Ansi`, and that would result in the behavior you're describing.